# Pick Different values from a column and write values correspondingly in R

Tags: r, excel, datetime, dataframe, time

I have a Dataframe that looks like :

**REPRODUCIBLE DATA:**

```
structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Jibran", class = "factor"), 
    Event = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("IN", 
    "OUT"), class = "factor"), Time = c("04/15/2015 00:31", "04/16/2015 20:10", 
    "04/21/2015 14:59", "04/22/2015 01:01", "04/22/2015 10:46", 
    "04/23/2015 00:58", "04/23/2015 14:50", "04/24/2015 01:37", 
    "04/25/2015 01:01", "04/27/2015 00:57", "04/17/2015 10:32", 
    "04/29/2015 15:03", "05/01/2015 00:44", "05/02/2015 01:19", 
    "05/02/2015 15:08", "05/03/2015 01:08", "05/03/2015 15:06", 
    "05/04/2015 01:01", "05/04/2015 15:11", "05/05/2015 01:08"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

The values I'm looking for are the ones in which the event changes, 
e.g:

User    | Event           | Time

Jibran    IN               4/21/2015 14:59
Jibran    OUT              4/22/2015 1:01
..
.. Values that occur when the next event is Different ( have values only when Event has In followed by Out)

The way I approached this problem is:

```
x = read.csv("TimeLog2.csv",header=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 0))

names(df)[1]<-paste("UserName")
names(df)[2]<-paste("Login")
names(df)[3]<-paste("Logout")


for(i in 1:length(x$Event))
{
   if(x$Event[[i]]== 'IN' && x$Event[[i+1]]== 'OUT'){
   df$Login[[i]]<-(x$Time[[i]])
   df$Logout[[i]]<-(x$Time[[i+1]])
   }
}
```

Which returns :

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Login", value = c(NA, NA, 4L)) : 
replacement has 3 rows, data has 0

The desired Output should look like :

[image]

One thing to make sure is that a change in event should only be written to the next dataframe only if it occurs on the same or next day(as per the date) to get accurate Login/Logout values.

---

Comment: You want a solution. I want data.

Comment: Picture attached is the dataset. @AndreElrico

Comment: I cannot work with pictures, I can only look at them.

Comment: Would also be good to post an example as close as possible to your real dataset. For example, post an example dataset for multiple users (2 users would be enough).

Comment: You can share your data by copying the result of: `dput(YOURDATA)`

Comment: Data : https://files.fm/u/krw42n8u @AndreElrico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#df1 <-
#    read.csv2("TimeLog2.csv", sep = ",")[,1:3]

library(data.table)

df1$Time2 <- df1$Time %>% as.Date(., format = "%m/%d/%Y", tz = 'GMT')
df1$grp   <- shift(cumsum(df1$Event == "OUT"), 1 , 0)

setDT(df1)[, dataDiff := c(.SD$Time2[-.N] - .SD$Time2[.N] > -2 , F)  ,by=grp]
df1 <- df1[, .SD[as.logical(cumsum(.SD$dataDiff)),], by=grp][,`:=`(dataDiff = NULL, Time2 = NULL)][]

dcast(df1, User + grp ~ Event)[,`:=`(grp = NULL)][]
```

Result:

```
#     User              IN            OUT
#1: Jibran 4/21/2015 14:59 4/22/2015 1:01
#2: Jibran 4/22/2015 10:46 4/23/2015 0:58
#3: Jibran 4/23/2015 14:50 4/24/2015 1:37
#4: Jibran  5/2/2015 15:08  5/3/2015 1:08
#5: Jibran  5/3/2015 15:06  5/4/2015 1:01
#6: Jibran  5/4/2015 15:11  5/5/2015 1:08
```

Answer (score 1):

**Data**

```
df = structure(list(User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Jibran", class = "factor"), 
Event = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("IN", 
"OUT"), class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(9L, 10L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 11L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("05/01/2015 00:44", "05/02/2015 01:19", 
"05/02/2015 15:08", "05/03/2015 01:08", "05/03/2015 15:06", 
"05/04/2015 01:01", "05/04/2015 15:11", "05/05/2015 01:08", 
"4/15/2015 0:31", "4/16/2015 20:10", "4/17/2015 10:32", "4/21/2015 14:59", 
"4/22/2015 1:01", "4/22/2015 10:46", "4/23/2015 0:58", "4/23/2015 14:50", 
"4/24/2015 1:37", "4/25/2015 1:01", "4/27/2015 0:57", "4/29/2015 15:03"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

**Solution**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  mutate(Time = mdy_hm(Time)) %>%                           # update to date variables
  group_by(id = rleid(Event)) %>%                           # create a grouping variable
  filter((Event == "IN" & Time == max(Time)) |              # keep max time for IN
         (Event == "OUT" & Time == min(Time))) %>%          # keep min time for OUT
  ungroup() %>%                                             # forget the grouping
  mutate(id = cumsum(Event == "IN")) %>%                    # create a new grouping variable
  spread(Event, Time) %>%                                   # reshape data
  filter(ceiling(difftime(OUT, IN, units="days")) < 2) %>%  # exclude cases where difference in time is 2+ days
  select(-id)                                               # remove grouping variable

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#     User   IN                  OUT                
#    <fct>  <dttm>              <dttm>             
# 1 Jibran 2015-04-21 14:59:00 2015-04-22 01:01:00
# 2 Jibran 2015-04-22 10:46:00 2015-04-23 00:58:00
# 3 Jibran 2015-04-23 14:50:00 2015-04-24 01:37:00
# 4 Jibran 2015-05-02 15:08:00 2015-05-03 01:08:00
# 5 Jibran 2015-05-03 15:06:00 2015-05-04 01:01:00
# 6 Jibran 2015-05-04 15:11:00 2015-05-05 01:08:00
```